# Ipython tab completion - identifying methods vs properties

Tags: python, ipython, tab-completion

When using the interactive ipython tab completion, is there a way easily identify which of the returned values are `properties` and which are `methods`?

I use `os` as an example below. I don't see a distinction of any kind. I know this could be done with `dir` but wanted to know if there was already a way to do this in ipython. It seems that it could be a time saver.

```
os.
Display all 203 possibilities? (y or n)
os.EX_CANTCREAT      os.confstr_names     os.pardir

os.EX_CONFIG         os.ctermid           os.path

os.EX_DATAERR        os.curdir            os.pathconf

os.EX_IOERR          os.defpath           os.pathconf_names

os.EX_NOHOST         os.devnull           os.pathsep

...
```

Comment: Perhaps the [see](http://inky.github.io/see/) module can be of some help. It provides nicer output than `dir` and appends `()` to names of callables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with the current state of the completion mechanism.
You could have a look at the [enhancement proposal](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPEP-11%3a-Tab-Completion-System-Refactor) for the completion machinery and suggest modifications if necessary.

Comment: thanks matt. outside of ipython, are there any good tools that will easily display this kind of information? say I want to look at a module and get a display of all the methods and properties, including the right syntax for each method. i know this can be done with some for loops but was hoping there was an easier way to see all this.

Comment: There are probably some tool, I've seen a few, but I can't find them, and I don't remember the name.